# disable specific log in n3k

Tags: cisco-nx-os

i have a N3K-C3064PQ-10GX and i receive the following log :

```
2020 Oct 13 04:36:10 GMT: %ARP-2-DUP_SRC_IP: arp [3565] Source address of packet received from 24e9.b39e.03bc on Vlan32(port-channel20) is duplicate of local, 185.x.x.x
```

is there anyway that set do not log %ARP-2-DUP_SRC_IP but log other informational ?
as i remember there was such feature in ios,
THanks,

Comment: I am only familiar with disabling specific messages on an ASA. I don't think IOS/NXOS has ever had a similar feature. However, there are filtering mechanisms: *logging discriminator* and *logging filter*

Comment: That message indicates something isn't right in your setup. The switch shouldn't be seeing another device with its IP.  Solve the issue and the message will go away.